# Send notification message(using message manager) as ajax response

Tags: magento2, frontend

The controller takes the Ajax request and after some required operations should return the HTML of the notification message using message manager so that it can be rendered on the front end using Javascript.

```
    $_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $messageManager = $_objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface');
    $block = $this->_layoutFactory->create()->getMessagesBlock()->addError('Configuration is wrong!');
    $block->setMessages($messageManager->getMessages(true));
    
    $resultJson = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();

    $mess= $block->getGroupedHtml();
    return $resultJson->setData([
        'messages' => $mess,
        'error' => '$error value comes here'
    ]);
```

But function `getGroupedHtml()` does not return any html.

Being a beginner to Magento, my queries are

What I am trying to do is feasible?
If yes, then what have missed I or done wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try remove line from your code:

```
$block->setMessages($messageManager->getMessages(true));
```

I don't know why you need it. Removing it should help.

Answer (score 0):

Here It is Hope this will help You

```
define ([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
], function ($, customerData) {
    'use strict';

    return function () {
        var msg = 'some message here';

        customerData.set('messages', {
            messages: [{
                type: 'success',
                text: msg
            }]
        });
    }
}
```